# HTAccess - Redirect all pages AND get data

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a quick question.

So I have my rule, which is;

```
RewriteRule    ^([a-z0-9\-\/]+)/?$    index.php?requested_page=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle requests.
```

How do I change this to forward any get data to the pages that get requested?
Index.php is a template basically, that pulls in data from other pages depending on which URL is requested. The template is basically as follows;

```
         $sitePageHashMap = array(
                "home" => "home",
                "pretty-link" => "pagename",
                "pretty-link" => "pagename",
                "pretty-link" => "pagename"
            );
```

Thanks,

Harry

Comment: By “any get data” you mean the original query string values of the request? If so, look at the flag `QSA`.

Comment: Yes I did, the code is below answered by anubhava as well for future reference to anybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use QSA flag:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)/?$ index.php?requested_page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.